# What does "a sense of" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have consulted this link, but I am not sure of my sentence. Does it mean "I have a feeling that EU will lose U.S."?
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258894/synonym-for-a-sense-of

"Against this backdrop, moves by U.S. lawmakers that could impact energy supplies in the region are unwelcome -- especially after three years of close coordination on sanctions.
"**There is a sense of loss of a partnership**," Berzina said of attitudes in Europe."

Source: http://money.cnn.com/2017/07/24/news/economy/EUrope-us-sanctions-natural-gas-russia/index.html?iid=SF_LN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence could be improved. **sense of loss of a partnership** is rather clumsy writing.

**Berzina said of attitudes in Europe** is a clue.  Berzina is describing attitudes in Europe, where there is "a sense of loss of a partnership."

In other words, where there is a sense (feeling, notion, idea, opinion, belief,  attitude) that the US-European partnership (on the matter of sanctions) is dissolving.

...where there is a feeling  *that* the partnership is failing or has already failed.